# Access to Google Play Developer API "as a service"

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-play-developer-api

I'm developing a service that requires access to the *Google Play Developer API* on behalf of my users.

I created an API project of type *Web Application*. It can successfully request the users' `androidpublisher` permission using an OAuth consent screen. Based on the documentation, it should be able to make requests to the *Google Play Developer API*.

But requests to the API fail with the following error:

`The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.`

From my understanding, the API Project needs to be linked to the Google Publisher Account from the Console (*Settings -> API access -> Linked projects*). However, the project doesn't appear in the list (since it's not owned by the user).

Is there any solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a solution to this. The only model the console supports for acting on behalf of developer users is for them to create the project in the Play Console, and you provide them a tool that they can use on their project.

Comment: OK. I ended up using Service Accounts, which I believe is the correct solution as it gives the users more granular control of what the server can access. Thanks